# How to get all sessions in Vaadin

Tags: java, session, vaadin

I want to know How many users are connected to my application in real time. I got the idea to loop on number of session that are open but I can't find how to do that. If you have another way to do it your suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Best solution i found so far is to count the sessions when they are created and destroyed.

```
public class VaadinSessionListener{

    private static volatile int activeSessions = 0;

    public static class VaadinSessionInitListener implements SessionInitListener{

        @Override
        public void sessionInit(SessionInitEvent event) throws ServiceException {

            incSessionCounter();            
        }
    }

    public static class VaadinSessionDestroyListener implements SessionDestroyListener{

        @Override
        public void sessionDestroy(SessionDestroyEvent event) {

            /*
             * check if HTTP Session is closing
             */
            if(event.getSession() != null && event.getSession().getSession() != null){

                decSessionCounter();
            }
        }
    }


    public static Integer getActiveSessions() {
        return activeSessions;
    }

    private synchronized static void decSessionCounter(){
        if(activeSessions > 0){
            activeSessions--;
        }
    }

    private synchronized static void incSessionCounter(){
        activeSessions++;
    }
}
```

then add the SessionListeners in the VaadinServlet init() method

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = true, ui = MyUI.class)
public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException {

        super.init(servletConfig);


        /*
         * Vaadin SessionListener
         */
        getService().addSessionInitListener(new VaadinSessionListener.VaadinSessionInitListener());
        getService().addSessionDestroyListener(new VaadinSessionListener.VaadinSessionDestroyListener());    
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work! I added `Servlet` class to my `UI` but it doesn't increment the counter. Is there something else that I have to change ?

Comment: The Servlet class should be already available inside the UI. which vaadin version and servlet version are you using?

Comment: Vaadin 7.2 with Maven. And I use `com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet` in Web.xml

Comment: my code example was for Servlet 3.0 specification. you probably have also to add the correct Servlet in the web.xml. com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet in web.xml is wrong.

Comment: It worked when I put the `Servlet` in an other java class and change the `Servlet` location in my `web.xml`. Thanks man the idea is good.

Answer (score 8):

## [Retraction]

Here is a *wrong* Answer. I mistakenly thought the cited method answers the Question, but it does not. **Consider this a retraction**; rather than delete this Answer I'll leave it so that others avoid making my mistake.

---

## `VaadinSession.getAllSessions()`

With Vaadin 7.2 came the addition of a static method, [`VaadinSession.getAllSessions`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/VaadinSession.html#getAllSessions(javax.servlet.http.HttpSession)). For history, see [Ticket # 13053](http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/13053).

That method returns a [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) of [`VaadinSession`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/VaadinSession.html) objects attached to a single [`HttpSession`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html).

This method tells you how many VaadinSession objects are running for *a single user’s HttpSession*, but does *not* tell you how many overall users are on your Vaadin app server.

Comment: This returns the vaadin sessions for a given http session. In order to achieve what was asked, the http sessions need to be collected as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770535/is-there-any-method-to-obtain-in-a-servlet-all-valid-session-keys-values-on-jett or with the Vaadin SessionInitListener