# Checking if a session variable exists in Vaadin

Tags: java, session, vaadin, dangerous-request

```
VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute("name")
&
VaadinSession.getCurrent().setAttribute("name", "actual nameson")
```

vs

```
getSession().getAttribute("name", username);
&
getSession().setAttribute("name", username);
```

are either of these correct methods to use Vaadin's Session management?
I cannot find understandable documentation on getting and setting a session in Vaadin.

**My current problem:**
if I try to Get a session variable, I get a nullpointerException, I tried to swallow it and continue but this makes Vaadin implode.

Is there a safe way to check if a Vaadin session (and specific variable) is set?

Do I have to initialize a session before I can use the variables?

more specifically, I want to check if a session exists before a user is redirected to the login screen. if the user is not logged in, the check throws a nullpointerException so a user who is not logged in cannot load the loginForm.

question @ [How to get all sessions in Vaadin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995677/how-to-get-all-sessions-in-vaadin?rq=1) is not related to my problem.

**one more thing**

```
boolean isLoggedIn = getSession().getAttribute("user") != null;
```

does not make Vaadin implode, so I am probably just doing a Java Fail™

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: the downvote is probably from a Google that led to the docs page: https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/main/setting+and+reading+session+attributes which is oudated and does not shed light to me.

Comment: Your Vaadin UI class is session scoped, i.e. (usually) one UI for each user session. So, usually you put session scoped variables directly or indirectly into UI class. If you are familar with Spring framework, you could use a @UIScoped bean. No need to access the servlet session directly, I think.

Comment: I have a JPA backend so I will look into creating a similar @UIScoped bean for this,
thank you for the hint!

Comment: Your wiki link is stating that it might be out dated. But it's not. Regarding spring, read [this](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Vaadin+Spring).

Comment: Woah, Spring can be used with JPA? I have been avoiding Spring as I though it would mean moving away from JPA.

Comment: Oh, my link is regarding Spring and Vaadin. But you can use Spring in conjunction with JPA, see spring data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115170/discussion-between-aj-otto-and-steffen-harbich).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly access the HTTP Session if needed, using [`VaadinService`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/VaadinService.html).

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) VaadinService.getCurrentRequest();
request.getSession().setAttribute("name", "actual nameson");
```

Comment: now i'm gonna read up on these functions and how the sessions are scoped, thank you so much, [Wijaya](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4306188/wijaya)

Comment: Another way to access the http session: VaadinSession.getCurrent().getSession();

Comment: You can also use `VaadinServletService.getCurrentServletRequest().getSession()`.